# jQuery focus contenteditable when caret gets inside

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div and upon pressing a button, new **contenteditable** span elements are put at the end of this div.

So when a user clicks on one of these new spans, it gets focused. But when using the arrow keys to navigate the div, if the user moves the caret inside one of the dynamic spans, it doen't get focused.

I tried a lot of googling, but couldn't find anything related.

For example:

```
<div contenteditable=true>
    aa
    <span contenteditable=true style="border: solid thin #000">bb</span>
    aa
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].onfocus = function(){alert('focused');};
</script>
```

I am trying to trigger the alert when user uses the arrow keys while inputting in the div to navigate inside the span. But `onfocus` doesn't seem to get triggered.

Comment: Can you provide the [mcve] code that would reproduce your issue, and - ideally - more clearly explain the problem? Also, it's almost certainly worth taking the [tour] if you haven't already, and reading the [ask] guidelines.

Comment: Sorry. I added an example now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will help you

```js
document.querySelector('div').onkeyup = function (e) {
        let selection = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        let spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');

        spans.forEach(function (span) {
            if( span.contains(selection.startContainer) ){
                alert('focused');
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<div contenteditable=true>
    aa
    <span contenteditable="true" style="border: solid thin #000">bb</span>
    aa
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot :)